# crash uiwebview without http or https in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uitextfield, nsstring

I want show the URL in Web View

here is my code

```
  let urlString:String = "https://www.apple.com"
        let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
        let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)

        urlTextField.text = urlString
```

if user forget to write http or https the app crashed how can I resolve this error

Comment: First of all, do not use force unwrapping. You can avoid the crash. Then you can check there is scheme and add if not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `starts(with:)` on string to detect if the url string starts with http/https, and if not, add the "http://" yourself (also, use safe `if let` instead of force unwrap):

```
var urlString: String = "www.apple.com"
if !urlString.starts(with: "http://") && !urlString.starts(with: "https://") {
      urlString = "http://\(urlString)"
}
if let url: URL = URL(string: urlString) {
    let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
    urlTextField.text = urlString
}
```